# How to I traverse/loop through a tree of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, loops, traversal

I have my tree which a want to traverse through, each subtree might have different length:

```js
const Tree = [
  {
    data: true,
    subTrees: [{
      data: true, subTrees: [{ data: true, subTrees: [] }]
    }]
  },
  {
    data: true,
    subTrees: [{
      data: true, subTrees: []
    }]
  },
  {
    data: true,
    subTrees: [{
      data: true, subTrees: [{ data: true, subTrees: [{ data: true, subTrees: [] }] }]
    }]
  },
  {
    data: true,
    subTrees: [{
      data: true, subTrees: [{ data: true, subTrees: [] }]
    }]
  }
]
```

How do I loop through each and every subTree so I can access the data in each node?

This is what I have now:

```js
function traverseTree(currentTree) {

  for (let i = 0; i < currentTree.length; i++) {
    
    // do something

    traverseTree(currentTree[i])

  }

}
```

Comment: `traverseTree(currentTree[i].subTrees)` instead of `traverseTree(currentTree[i])`

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli Wow I feel so dumb, thanks!

Comment: @CarlssonK don't. It happens to all.

Answer (score 0):

you can use it:

```
const traverseTree = (arr) => {
    arr.forEach(el => {
        // do something
        traverseTree(el.subTrees);
    });
};

traverseTree(Tree);
```

Comment: yup, and `el.data` would access `data` throughout the tree